# Plupload, directly open dialog on instance

Tags: plupload

I have a page in order to upload some file on a website. In this page is an instance of plupload.

[image: state on open]

My wish is that when plupload is instanced, the filebrowser dialog automatically open, like a click on Add files but without doing this click.

Edit: the plupload instance is in flash, so i search for a possibilty to call a function in flash in order to open the filebrowser in my computer.

I'm not able to find a solution.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can't. At least not in Flash, nor in Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

That "add files" button is a flash button. So, you cant trigger it automatically simply, without tewaking that file. Plupload is open source, so i guess the source file is available. You have to find the function which gets executed on click, and set that to execute on load.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i forgot to explain that. it's my problem, interact with flash. I thought perhaps plupload has an event wich can call a function in flash but i find nothing.

Comment: It is not possible to trigger file dialog for flash programmatically.